# If else logic in controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, django

I have four buttons. Below are their html,

```
<label>Severity *</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="sModal()" name="s" ng-model="cpform.severity">{{cpform.severity}}</button>

                <label>Occurence *</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="OModal()" name="o" ng-model="cpform.occurence">{{cpform.occurence}}</button>

                <label>Detection *</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-click="siverifydetectionModal()" name="detection" ng-model="cpform.detection">{{cpform.detection}}</button>

                <label>RPN</label>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-model="cpform.risk_score">{{cpform.severity*cpform.occurence*cpform.detection}}</button>
```

All these 4 buttons are displayed in the modal. The values for the first three buttons are got from different modals. Here, I have displayed the Product value in the last button in RPN. When I tried to save the value, I was able to save the values of first three buttons except the last button value.

Below is my code in the controller part:

```
$scope.cpform = {
                                summary: r_header.summary,
                                severity:r_header.severity,
                                occurence:r_header.occurence,
                                detection:r_header.detection,
                                risk_score: r_header.risk_score,
                                nocpz: nocpz_checked,
                                route: r_header.route,
                                layers: r_header.layers,
                                comments: r_header.comments,
                                risks: risk_id_list,


                            };

        }



        $scope.updateReview = function (cpform, formname) {
            $scope.uprev_submit_disabled = true;
            var updated_field_list = [];

            if (r_header.revSeverity[0] != null) {
                angular.forEach($scope.cpform, function(value, key) {
                    //if(key[0] == '$') return;
                    console.log("Chck", value, key);
                    if (!formname[key].$pristine) {
                        updated_field_list.push(key);
                    }
                    console.log("CPZ", key, formname[key].$pristine)
                 });
```

I want to pass the Product Value which I get in the RPN button through the risk_score variable mentioned in the controller. I'm passing the $scope.cpform to the views and respectively to models in order to save it. Anybody please tell me how to save the Product value which I get in RPN button to the db. I want to pass and save value in risk_score variable.

Comment: Put a name for last button and try

Comment: Values are getting saved. risk_score is a field in the database now. I want to the replace the values of risk_score with the value which I get in the RPN button. i.e Product value. Any suggestions?